# Pass value of theme variable to child component in Angular

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-components

I'm trying to pass a color, which is defined as an SCSS theme variable, as an input variable to a custom component. Let me give you a boiled-down example of my code, which is also on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-9vjmce?file=src/app/app.component.html).

The custom component looks something like this:

**hello.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "hello",
  template: `<p style="color: {{ color }}">Hello {{ name }}!</p>`
})
export class HelloComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() color: string;
}
```

Now I use it in my app as follows:

**app.component.html:**

```
<p>Hello Peter!</p>
<hello name="Alice" color="blue"></hello>
<hello name="Bob" color="$primary"></hello>
```

The first line (Peter) is styled in **app.component.scss:**

```
@import "./theme_variables.scss";

p { color: $primary; }
```

It uses a variable from **`theme_variables.scss`:**

```
$primary: #804000;
```

The second line (Alice) successfully passes the color "blue" to the hello-Component where it is applied to the paragraph style. But the last line (Bob) fails to pass the primary color to the component. The text is just black.

So my question is:

**How can I pass the value of an SCSS variable (`$primary`) to a custom component (`hello`)?**

If possible, I don't want to re-define colors that are already defined in my theme variables and used throughout my app.

Comment: Is your theme_varriables.scss is having fixed value of $primary ? If yes then  1) define all these theme varriables in some constant file . 2) read values from the constant in theme scss file . 3) import the same constant file into you component and use the value corresponding to primary.

Comment: @ShivanshSeth Yes, the value of $primary is constant. But I might want to use the component at different places with different colors. So defining all possible variables in another file might be cumbersome.

Comment: oh ! I see. So it means [attr.fill]="color" here 'color' is a component specific varriable and may have diffrent value based on the @Input value.  How & where we are defining the logic which color for which component?

Comment: @ShivanshSeth My template files define SVGs with different text boxes `<svg:g text-box color="..." ...>...</svg:g>`. So that's where I probably need to pass the desired color, possibly using a SASS variable.

Comment: I have added a small code example for changing dynamic color on click on SVG element. hope this helps you to write logic further. Will be happy if need further help :)

Comment: @ShivanshSeth Thanks for your input. I updated my question with a more minimal code example without the distracting SVG, to hopefully clarify my root problem.

Comment: thanks, I tried to use the scss variable as an argument but seems its not feasible to use the variable after compilation. Still i am looking if i will find. Something will update you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Added Updatd solution : Below code show change color on SVG rectangle click ( this might help you , here I used Click event you can add as per your requirement)

componene.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-svg',
  templateUrl: './svg.component.svg',
  styleUrls: ['./svg.component.css']
})
export class SvgComponent {
  fillColor = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)';

  changeColor() {
   // here in this method we can write our logic to define which color
    const r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const g = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    const b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 256);
    this.fillColor = `rgb(${r}, ${g}, ${b})`;
  }
}
```

**svg.component.svg**

```
<svg>
  <g>
    <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" [attr.fill]="fillColor" (click)="changeColor()" />
    <text x="120" y="50">click the rectangle to change the fill color</text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Alternate : in component specific CSS file but this will be static value based on the --primary value.

```
:root {
  **--primary-color: hsl(332, 61%, 78%);**
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.test {
  **background: var(--primary-color);**
}

.icon {
  **color: var(--primary-color);
  fill: currentColor;**
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
}
```